# How to get some data out of an array in swift?

Tags: swift

Here is my problem: I have an plist file, which have a simple strut:
root object is an array, and there are 2 sections in the array, each of them are dictionary including 2 pair key-value data:

[image]

and I'm going to create a tableView to show the datas, but I can't get the content out of the array :

[image]
here is how i declared my dataArray:

```
var plistArray = [AnyObject]()
```

can some one help me?

Comment: @rmaddy has answered your question brilliantly. I just want to explain the second error above (which he solved for you).  When you defined imgaName it was inside the {} of an if statement.  Once you leave the if statement behind, imgaName disappears. It only exists inside those {}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to properly cast at each level:

```
if let innerArray = plistArray[0] as? [AnyObject] {
    if let dataDic = innerArray[indexPath.row] as? [String:String] {
        if let imageName = dataDic["Pic"] {
            cell?.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
        }
    }
}
```

But why are you using `AnyObject` when you know what the plist contains? Use proper types. You know it's an array of arrays of dictionaries with String keys and String values.

```
var plistArray = [[[String:String]]]()
```

Then all you need is:

```
if let imageName = plistArray[0][indexPath.row]["Pic"] {
    cell?.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much , can I ask one more question? if I want declare an variable in swift , what is the difference between : `var array : array`  and `var array :[Any]?` , and how to declared an empty array? `var array:[ ]` or `var array:[ ]()` seems don't work

Comment: May I suggest you spend time reading [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/) book provided by Apple. It will answer such basic questions.